# How does CSS work with lots of same classes?

Tags: css

I'm curious about what impact does `CSS` have in the following situation or rather how does `CSS` change *style* for many same classes in general. I'm not particulary good at phrasing questions because English is not my first language and I'm not very familiar with all the programming terms, that's why I couldn't find anything online.

Let's say I have very large number of divs  `<div class="my-div">` and `.my-div { background-color: red; }`

How does `CSS` handle this situation? Does it *style* all `div-s` in one simple round or is there something more complex involved?

Im asking this because I can't decide if to use small .png images or `HTML` elements and `CSS` for map's markers, I would prefer the last one in order to use `:hover` and other neat `CSS` tricks.

Comment: @HTMLNoob [50000 elements might not be an exaggeration](https://jsfiddle.net/28rzLkb1/).

Comment: lol, ok find me a website that used 50,000 elements.

Comment: Well, Oriol has just proven that CSS will handle 50,000 elements very well.

Comment: Dont tell me your actually looking @Oriol

Comment: @HTMLNoob It seems it's having some problems with a bit more [complex CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/28rzLkb1/1/) but Im not sure how bad is it for normal PCs because I have pretty powerful one.

Comment: @Oriol Does anyone know any CSS reference that explains my question in more detail or could you answer it yourself? Im really interested in how CSS works with numerous elements same classes.

Comment: @Solo lol you crashed my computer. Anyway, the reason the browser was going bonkers is that there is a transform on the z axis. In other words 50,000 elements performing 3 Dimensional transformations.

Comment: @Solo The specification does not define what browsers should do under the hood, that's implementation-dependent, and I don't know what major implementations do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for all general purposes the browser will handle a large number of elements quite effectively. And yes the CSS styles all the divs with one simple round.